# DoCmd.OutputTo fails intermitantly on different items within a list - Error 2501

Tags: ms-access, vba, report, ms-access-2010

The DoCmd.OutputTo command fails on different items within a list with Error 2501.  Pictured below is my subroutine (much code removed).  It loops through a list of vendors, sending invoices via email.  We are running Access 365 with linked tables to a SQL Server 2008R2.  Each time I run the routine, the code fails on a different supplier (sometimes no failures).  There is one attachment per outgoing email.  Each attachment has a unique file name.  Attachments are written to the hard drive to avoid network lag.  The report is fairly complex, sometimes calling functions which hit linked tables.  Need help with how to make the function more robust to not fail.

```vb
Sub EmailInvoices() 
  InvFilePath = "C:\temp\"
  On Error GoTo EmailInvoicesProblem

  ' loop through the list of suppliers, this invoice type, this date
  For x = 1 To SupplierCount

    SQLStr3 = "SELECT * from " & RptTypeDtlQry & WhereClause
    DoCmd.OpenReport RptName, acViewDesign, , , acHidden
        Set Inv_rpt = Reports(RptName)
        Inv_rpt.RecordSource = SQLStr3
        Inv_rpt.Caption = "Supplier " & rst!supplier_code & " " & InvType & " Invoices"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, RptName, acSaveYes

    'image the invoice, attach the invoice to the email, and then delete the image
    InvFileName = InvFilePath & rst!supplier_code & ".pdf"
  TryAgain:
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, RptName, acFormatPDF, InvFileName, False
    objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add (InvFileName)
    fso.DeleteFile (InvFileName)

    ' send all the invoices of this supplier, this invoice type, this date in a single email.
    objOutlookMsg.Send

  NextSupplier:
    rst.MoveNext
Next x
rst.Close
Exit Sub

End Sub  'EmailInvoices()
```

Comment: Error 2501 typically means there's no data in your report - you can trap errors and report on Err.Description - your code seems to be split up in text above - you could preprocess SQL with a recordset and first determine if there's any records before trying to create the report

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the report file name has invalid characters? (would have posted this as a comment but don't have enough points)

Can you put some Debug.Print statements in to show what the variables are when it works and when it doesn't?